# Defining a dynamic threshold for active noise reduction

Tags: python, scipy, pyaudio, wave

Is there any way to define a dynamic threshold for filtering noise in python? I am trying to achieve active noise reduction using python. What I want to achieve is that everything that is below the threshold will be filtered (this will be the ones classified as unwanted noise). On the other hand, everything above the threshold (i.e. voice) will be untouched. Is there already an available script for this kind of idea?

Comment: Without knowing (1) the API you are using (2) the format of your data, it is almost impossible to answer your question... You didn't even say if you want to filter noise in sound, in image or in video!

Comment: @sciroccorics I want to filter sound in audio

Comment: OK, so now we need the answer of the two other questions: API and data format. And some code I have tried...